# binary operator '< ' cannot be applied two T operands

Tags: swift

My code as below, i want the function `maxNumer` not only just for one type:

```
var numbers3 = [3,9,23,67,34,2,7,0,1]

func maxNumer<T>(array:[T]) -> T {
    var maxNumer = array[0]
    for var i = 0; i < array.count-1; i++ {
        if maxNumer < array[i+1] { //This line gets error as title
            maxNumer = array[i+1]
        }
    }
    return maxNumer
}
```

How should i change it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell Swift that `T` conforms to `Comparable` protocol in order for it to allow using operator `<` on objects of type `T`:

```
func maxNumer<T : Comparable>(array:[T]) -> T {
//                ^^^^^^^^^^
    var maxNumer = array[0]
    for var i = 0; i < array.count-1; i++ {
        if maxNumer < array[i+1] { //This line gets error as title
            maxNumer = array[i+1]
        }
    }
    return maxNumer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.0 + :**

For example : If you wanted to solve find the second largest element in the array you can use Generics in Swift , here is solution using comparable protocol:

```
var intArray = [20, 10, 33, 8, 9, 5, 40]
var doubleArray = [3.5, 7.0, 10.5, 4.0, 5.5, 1.0]
var stringArray = ["apple", "banana", "Cat", "dog"]


func getLargest <T:Comparable>(array: [T]) -> T {
    let a = array
    var first = a[0]
    var second = a[0]
    
    for i in 0..<a.count {
        if first < a[i] {
            second = first
            first = a[i]
        }
        else if ( a[i] > second && a[i] != first) {
            second = a[i]
        }
    }
    
    return second
}

print(getLargest(array: intArray))
print(getLargest(array: doubleArray))
print(getLargest(array: stringArray))
```

> Output :
>
> 33
> 7.0 banana